# Get REST API for a XML Response

Tags: apex, rest-api, xml

I am writing a REST API that simply gets a response for a url. However the challenging part is that the response is in xml format instead of json. I am not sure how to parse this xml and get specific values such as Status, Facility Description (all inside the event tag) and Ship Date. Here is what I have so far but i am pretty stuck. Thank you for the help.

Sample XML response:

```
<ShipmentStatus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Packages> 
   <Package>
      <Events> 
        <Event>
           <Status>AA</Status>
           <Description>DATA ENTRY</Description> 
           <EventTime>2014-03-13T10:48:05.14</EventTime> 
           <Facility>Commerce</Facility> 
           <City>COMMERCE</City>
           <State>CA</State>
           <Zip>90040</Zip>
        </Event>
      </Events>
      <Tracking>C11421500000014</Tracking> 
      <Exp_Del_Date>2014-03-14T00:00:00</Exp_Del_Date> 
      <ShipDate>2014-03-13T00:00:00</ShipDate> 
      <Delivered>false</Delivered>
      <Zip>90210</Zip>
      <Service>S</Service>
      <POD/>
      <Error/>
   </Package> 
</Packages>
<Note>Results Provided by OnTrac at 3/13/2014 10:48 AM</Note>
<Error/> 
</ShipmentStatus>
```

My attempt at REST API:

```
Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        // url that returns the XML in the response body
        TrackingNumber ='123456';
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.shippingstatus.net/ShippingServices.svc/V5/shipments?tn=' + TrackingNumber);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        
        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode packages = doc.getRootElement(); //is packages the root element?
        
        for(Dom.XMLNode child : packages.getChildElements()) {
           System.debug(child.getText());  //but how do I get specific tag values like status, facility, description etc???
        }
```

Latest Attempt:

```
public class TracProcess {
    
    public class trackNumberInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String trackingNumber;
        
    }
    
    
    public void getTrackingStatus(String trackingNumber){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        // url that returns the XML in the response body
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.somewebsiteurl.com/WebServices/V1/shipments?tn='+trackingNumber);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        
        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();
        
//How do i call the classes that I have created in this web service?
        

    }
    
    public class ShipmentStatus{
    Packages packages;
    Note note;
    Error error;

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        // more looping
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            switch on child.getName(){
                when 'Packages'{
                    packages = new Packages();
                    packages.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Note'{
                    note = new Note();
                    note.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Error'{
                    error = new Error();
                    error.deserialize(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    
    public class Packages{
        Package package; //keeps on showing error on this because it is a reserved identifier? how do i fix this?
        
        public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
            for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
                if(child.getName() == 'Package'){
                    package = new Package();

                    package.deserialize(child);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    
    public class Package{
        Events events;
        Tracking tracking;
        Exp_Del_Date expDelDate;
        ShipDate sd;
        Delivered delivered;
        Zip zip;
        Service service;
        POD pod;
        Error error;
        
       

    public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
        
        for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
            switch on child.getName(){
                when 'Events'{
                    events = new Events();
                    events.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Tracking'{
                    tracking = new Tracking();
                    tracking.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Exp_Del_Date'{
                    expDelDate = new Exp_Del_Date();
                    expDelDate.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'ShipDate'{
                    sd = new ShipDate();
                    expDelDate.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Delivered'{
                    delivered = new Delivered();
                    delivered.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Zip'{
                    zip = new Zip();
                    zip.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Service'{
                    service = new Service();
                    service.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'POD'{
                    pod = new POD();
                    pod.deserialize(child);
                }
                when 'Error'{
                    error = new Error();
                    error.deserialize(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
    public class Events{
    // When we get to items that only contain primitive values, it's time
    //  to just extract them directly
        String Event;
        String Status;
        String Description; //should this be string?
        DateTime EventTime;
        String Facility;
        String City;
        String State;
        String Zip;
        
        public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
            for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
                switch on child.getName(){
                    when 'Event'{
                        Event = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'Status'{
                        Status = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'Description'{
                        Description = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'EventTime'{
                        EventTime = (DateTime)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'Facility'{
                        Facility = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'City'{
                        City = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'State'{
                        State = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                    when 'Zip'{
                        Zip = (String)child.getValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: I am still unsure about this. So once I write a "parser" class then how does the REST API call it? Also, do I have to put the xml response as a string in the code?

Comment: With what you've shown us so far, you don't have a REST API. Instead, you're making a _callout_ to a REST API. At the very bottom of the example that I provided in the linked question, there is a example of usage. Basically, you create an instance of the outermost class, and then call `deserialize()` and pass the parsed root element into that method.

Comment: Apologize for the mistake in terminology. You are right I am calling a REST API and the apex just retrieves/gets the response and parses. I am going to attempt the code you provided and paste my attempt here today because I am still unsure. Thank you

Comment: @DerekF Here is my latest attempt. I am not sure if this is correct. I am not sure how  to write the class for tags such as Tracking/ShipDate etc. Also, once this is parsed how do i convert this as output so I can pass those values in the web service?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do you call the deserialization classes?

The same way you call any other method, really.

- Make an instance of the class
- Call the method and pass arguments

That's really all there is to it

```java
public void getTrackingStatus(String trackingNumber){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        // url that returns the XML in the response body
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.somewebsiteurl.com/WebServices/V1/shipments?tn='+trackingNumber);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
        
        //Retrieve the root element for this document.
        Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();

        // Create an instance of the class
        ShipmentStatus status = new ShipmentStatus();

        // Call the method
        status.deserialize(root);
}
```

After you get the root XML Node into the top-level deserialization class, the work that you did in the deserialization method ensures that the rest of the work just happens.

#### How do I work around reserved keywords?

Since you're in control of the classes you're using for deserialization, you can simply rename problematic items

So instead of `Package`, you could use `xPackage` or `Pkg` instead

```java
public class Packages{
        // "package" is problematic, so just use another name
        Pkg myPkg;
        
        public void deserialize(Dom.XmlNode node){
            for(Dom.XmlNode child :node.getChildren()){
                if(child.getName() == 'Package'){
                    myPkg = new Pkg();

                    package.deserialize(child);
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    public class Pkg{
        Events events;
        Tracking tracking;
        Exp_Del_Date expDelDate;
        ShipDate sd;
        Delivered delivered;
        Zip zip;
        Service service;
        POD pod;
        Error error;
```

#### What do I do with [piece of data]?

The safe approach is to just treat it as a string

If you don't care about a particular piece of data, you could just simply ignore it.

e.g. instead of

```
when 'Description'{
    Description = (String)child.getValue();
}
```

you could just do nothing

```
when 'Description'{
}
```

or possibly remove the entire "when" block (though you may need to have a `when else {}` to compensate)